# Caching results of query when filters are unchanged

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I am building a contact management sort system. I am having a list page which has several filters to filter the results such as "area", "category", etc. And also I have search fields for name, address and contact info.

Suppose I set area as "Chicago" and category as "Family" and then press "apply filters" (filters and search fields will be submitted), I will get the result. Now if I had mentioned something in name filed then Il attach a where query to the resulting activerelation.

Suppose Ive got a result with above filters in one request. Then I want to search a different name, Ill have to query the database with the filters of are and category again which is not necessary.. is there a way to cache results from previous search?

Comment: "category again which is not necessary" -- why is this true?

Comment: coz itll probably return the same set of records...? unless someone adds a contact matching those particular filters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend not worrying about this until you can show you have a problem.

If you did have a problem you could:

- Return all results and do the filtering in JavaScript
- Cache all results on the server and do the filtering in Ruby there

Comment: Thank you. Thats a very wise advice. Then Ill address this issue when problems arise. :) Thanks!